# Howto point to typescript file instead of javascript file karma runner webstorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I have my project setup in WebStorm to transpile TypeScript into JavaScript etc.
So I write my code as well as my tests in TypeScript.

When I run "Karma with coverage" in webstorm it all runs fine.

But, when for example a tests fails, the output keeps pointing to the javascript files. So when I click the failing test, it opens up the javascript file instead of the typescript file

[image]

Is there a way to integrate the mappings here as well?

My current preprocessor setup:

```
preprocessors: {
  'app/resources/**/*.ts': ['typescript'],
  //'app/resources/**/!(*spec).ts': ['sourcemap', 'coverage'],
  'app/resources/**/!(*spec).js': ['sourcemap', 'coverage'],
  'app/resources/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
```

I've taken a look at:
https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor and did a search for typescript. Basically I only find preprocessor that compile/transpile the typescript files, but that is something I already do in my test process. So I believe I can just leave the 'typescript' preprocessor out?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You should modify karma.conf and add 'coverage' for ts files. Something like follow:

```
preprocessors: {
            'test/*Test.ts':['typescript'],
            'src/*.ts':['typescript','coverage'],
        },
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.. I only get coverage for my js files.

Comment: I've added my current preprocessor setup to the question

Comment: Sorry I forget about [karma-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sourcemap-loader). The full solution is: `'src/*.ts':['typescript','coverage', 'sourcemap'],` Ho it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13081