# Angular 2 + Karma-JSPM + TypeScript source & Jasmine Spec cannot setup test coverage

Tags: angularjs, typescript, code-coverage, karma-runner, jspm

I have an Angular 2 project set-up that currently uses SystemJS + JSPM + frankwallis/plugin-typescript to load up my TypeScript files on the fly for a quick and easy development workflow.  I have also setup Karma + Jasmine basic testing utilising Karma-JSPM so I am not repeating config which also works ok.

The problem I am having (and actually don't know whether it is possible) is I cannot set-up coverage for these as the files are not physically transpiled (JSPM and the frankwallis/plugin-typescript loader take care of this) and the coverage preprocessor part fails as it cannot read the TypeScript or something?

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './src',

    frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],

    jspm: {
      loadFiles: [
        'app/**/*.spec.ts'
      ],
      serveFiles: [
        'app/**/*!(*.spec).ts',
        'typings/**/*.*',
        'tsconfig.json'
      ]
    },

    preprocessors: {
      // Throws errors about unexpected token / not a string or buffer
      //'app/**/*!(*.spec).ts': ['coverage'] 
    },

    ... other parts removed for brevity

    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-jspm',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        { type: 'json', subdir: '../../coverage', file: 'coverage-final.json' }
      ]
    },

  })
}
```

Searching around I have seen people mention this on the Karma-JSPM github issues but no real solution was mentioned other than finding an 'instrumentor' for the coverageReporter that can read TypeScript but didn't really understand.

Full current code (without coverage) is [here](https://github.com/ChrisMurphy/ng2-seed/tree/b7c53a2d027f4c2ef3850b0f2d3354d5f9b07437).

Edit: I have also found [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633043/howto-point-to-typescript-file-instead-of-javascript-file-karma-runner-webstorm) but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work, I'm also trying to get `karma-jspm` and `karma-coverage` playing nicely together....